# How to use CakePHP's database.php file for custom scripts?

Tags: database, class, cakephp

Can you help me how to use class defined in CakePHP's /config/database.php file, for my custom scripts? I need to use defined array for db connection.

Tnx in adv!

Comment: Can you clarify the question? What kind of scripts are you talking about? Why do you want them to be in the database.php file?

Comment: no, i don't want to change anything in database.php file. all i want is to create my own scripts that will use mysql parameters from database.php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing magic about this class. It works the same as any other PHP class.

```
<?php

include("path/to/cake/config/database.php");
$db = new DATABASE_CONFIG;

echo $db->default['login'];
echo $db->default['password'];
echo $db->default['database'];

?>
```

Now you can reference the variables like you would with any other class.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for something similar to Rails' migrations, i.e. scripts that run within the context of the framework. There have been efforts to create such a thing (see Joel Moss' [article](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/cake-db-migrations-v2-1) in the Bakery).

What I tend to do is to keep a set of DDL scripts in a `_meta/` directory of my project. I execute these directly on the database so they have no need to read info from `database.php`. If you're set on using Cake's runtime context, my way won't help you, but maybe Joel's will.